# Invoking a method using reflection on a singleton object

Tags: c#, reflection, singleton

So I have the following:

```
public class Singleton
{

  private Singleton(){}

  public static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

  public string DoSomething(){ ... }

  public string DoSomethingElse(){ ... }

}
```

Using reflection how can I invoke the DoSomething Method?

Reason I ask is because I store the method names in XML and dynamically create the UI. For example I'm dynamically creating a button and telling it what method to call via reflection when the button is clicked. In some cases it would be DoSomething or in others it would be DoSomethingElse.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Untested, but should work...

```
string methodName = "DoSomething"; // e.g. read from XML
MethodInfo method = typeof(Singleton).GetMethod(methodName);
FieldInfo field = typeof(Singleton).GetField("instance",
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
object instance = field.GetValue(null);
method.Invoke(instance, Type.EmptyTypes);
```

Comment: great thankyou. That works. Except couldn't find Types.Empty. 
Do you mean Type.EmptyTypes?

Answer (score 4):

Great job. Thanks.

Here's the same approach with slight modification for cases that one can't have a reference to the remote assembly. We just need to know basic things such as the class fullname (i.e namespace.classname and the path to the remote assembly).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Assembly asm = null;
        string assemblyPath = @"C:\works\...\StaticMembers.dll" 
        string classFullname = "StaticMembers.MySingleton";
        string doSomethingMethodName = "DoSomething";
        string doSomethingElseMethodName = "DoSomethingElse";

        asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
        if (asm == null)
           throw new FileNotFoundException();


        Type[] types = asm.GetTypes();
        Type theSingletonType = null;
        foreach(Type ty in types)
        {
            if (ty.FullName.Equals(classFullname))
            {
                theSingletonType = ty;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (theSingletonType == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type was not found!");
            return;
        }
        MethodInfo doSomethingMethodInfo = 
                    theSingletonType.GetMethod(doSomethingMethodName );


        FieldInfo field = theSingletonType.GetField("instance", 
                           BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        object instance = field.GetValue(null);

        string msg = (string)doSomethingMethodInfo.Invoke(instance, Type.EmptyTypes);

        Console.WriteLine(msg);

        MethodInfo somethingElse  = theSingletonType.GetMethod(
                                       doSomethingElseMethodName );
        msg = (string)doSomethingElse.Invoke(instance, Type.EmptyTypes);
        Console.WriteLine(msg);}
```